# Different Toolbar/CollapsingToolbarLayout for each fragment inside a ViewPager

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-viewgroup

Is it possible to have for each `Fragment` inside a `ViewPager` different `ViewGroups` in the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`/`Toolbar`?

I would like to be able to swipe between pages and have different controls inside `CollapsingToolbarLayout` that interact with their respective `Fragment`in the `ViewPager`, so that they can be hidden while scrolling each fragment inside the `ViewPager`.

Regards.

Comment: you could have a second `ViewPager` inside the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` that uses a `OnPageChangeListener` to sync the pages

Comment: @karaokyo Sounds good. Right now I am adding and removing the `ViewGroup` from the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` as the pages of the first `ViewPager` change, but that has proven to be unreliable since the information contained in the `ViewGroup` isn't preserved when the fragments must restore their state. Would your solution solve this issue?

Comment: No, if you want to save a state you would have to use some persistent data store like shared preferences or a database. You could also store state variables in your `Activity` and update them via fragment interaction listeners.

Comment: @karaokyo I'm referring to the `Fragment's` instance state. The one saved when doing `setRetainInstance(true)`.

Comment: That would work if you're just talking about orientation changes

Comment: @karaokyo But that's the point. It isn't working since I am adding the views to the `CollapsingToolbarLayout`. Is it possible to communicate the `Fragments` between both `ViewPagers`?

Comment: If you're looking for some magic solution that handles state persistence for you, it doesn't exist. Obviously, I have no idea what exactly you need to persist, but you could look into storage libraries like [Paper](https://github.com/pilgr/Paper).

Comment: @karaokyo What I want is to retain the instance state of the `ViewGroups` inside the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` since the controls contained in them will be communicating with each respective `Fragment` inside the `ViewPager` and configuration changes need to preserve the values entered by the user.